# How to obtain, based on an origin and destination, the nearest bus route?

Tags: java, google-maps, android-studio

I'm doing an app on Android Studio about bus routes in my city, and it's a function I'd like to include. But I've looked for how to do it, and I have not found anything that comes close.

I have bus routes in a .JSON file (lat and long) which are plotted on Maps. Those routes I want to use them for when the user selects a destination, the application tells him which bus route is closest.
Do you recommend using SQL to store the routes and make queries, or not? Any related comment, is welcome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data you can use Dijkstra algorithm to get the short's path between nodes in a graph
Create a graph with  nodes representing the bus location